# Running Hadoop on Cloud platform

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

please tell me how to run wordcount and Terasort Mapreduce jobs of maximum size 1GB on Google Cloud, Ibm Cloud and Microsoft cloud

Answer (score 0):

1. You can login into the cloud-
2. Make a jar of your wordcount and Tera sort map reduce program, you can use eclipse for this.
3. Use any FTP software like winscp, and move the jar to the cloud. For this you have to provide the ip address of the cloud and so on..
4. Now you can use standard hadoop jar command to run the jar. Normal syntax could be

> hadoop jar Jar_name Package_name.Driver_Class_name Input_path_HDFS
>   Output_path_hdfs

For Terasort, pls use following link 
[Michael-Noll-Terasort](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2011/04/09/benchmarking-and-stress-testing-an-hadoop-cluster-with-terasort-testdfsio-nnbench-mrbench/)

I hope it would help..